# When language is set to French, decimal point separator ',' is ignored in binding to a double property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, localization, ivalueconverter

So I have an Entry bound to a double property with `Keyboard="Numeric"`.

- NO `StringFormat` is used, and not modifying/forcing culture at app level.
- Confirmed that in French the decimal point separator character is "," so "." won't be an allowed character:

  ```
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator equals ','
  ```

The issue is when I type "12,3", in the property setter the value is equal to 123. And of course at the end it displays 123 in the Entry field instead of "12,3".

#### xaml

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
```

#### C#

```
private double _MyProp;

public double MyProperty
{
    get { return _MyProp; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _MyProp, value); }
}
```

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a [<s>Xamarin.Forms issue</s>](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13763) [Fixed in #5005](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5005), as a workaround, use a value converter:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <app1:DecimalPointFixConverter x:Key="DecimalPointFixConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Converter={x:StaticResource DecimalPointFixConverter}}"/>
```

#### DecimalPointFixConverter.cs

```
public class DecimalPointFixConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as string)?.Replace(',', '.') ?? value;
    }
}
```

#### Related question

[Decimal point is being removed in Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73550567/5228202)