# Decimal point is being removed in Entry

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cultureinfo, ivalueconverter

My converter is the following

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is decimal)
                   return value.ToString ();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       decimal dec;
       if (decimal.TryParse(value as string, out dec))
           return dec;
       else
           return 0;
    }
}
```

When I enter a number

[image: Number 55]

Next entered the separator

[image: Save as 55]

When I enter the decimal

[image]

ends as 55

In the view
before

[image]

after

[image]

Resource:

```
   <support:DecimalConverter x:Key="DecimalConverter" />
```

Entry defined in the XAML

```
 <Entry
            BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding BackgroundColorAmountEntry}"
            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsByAmount}" Keyboard="Numeric"
            Text="{TemplateBinding CommissionWithTaxAmount,
            Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}" />
```

How could I solve it if I want it to be according to the culture?

Comment: According to your ideas, I want to know if you have set this in the XAML file: "ConverterParameter = dec".

Comment: I have it as Converter, I already add the definition of the entry in xaml

Comment: what is the language of the phone/emulator ? what is the value of  parameter culture ?

Comment: It was the language of the cell phone, I had it in us and the culture took it in es-Ar.
But the same in other cell phones the keyboard the comma is disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce "en-us" culture for [TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-decimal-tryparse(system-string-system-globalization-numberstyles-system-iformatprovider-system-decimal@))

```
public class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is decimal)
                   return value.ToString ();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       decimal dec;
        var style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
        var cultureEnUs = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        if (decimal.TryParse(value as string, style, cultureEnUs, out dec))
           return dec;
       else
           return 0;
    }
}
```

#### Alternative approach

[When language is set to French, decimal point separator ',' is ignored in binding to a double property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66401385/5228202)